# Import Excel sheet into MySQL

Tags: python, beginner, mysql, excel

This is the first project I have coded using Python.

Therefore, I am looking for someone to give me some comments to further improve my code.

#### Purpose of the application

This application help the staff in my organization to import the spreadsheet and store it into the database.

#### Flow

1. User would need to provide the document location before the application execute.
2. System will extract the information from spreadsheet and import into the database.

#### Source Code

Below is my source code.

The link below is the complete source code on Github,
[https://github.com/WeeHong/0703-Extractor/blob/master/Main.ipynb](https://github.com/WeeHong/0703-Extractor/blob/d037a2a53428dc37c77e6fd9803e2869383f3d01/Main.ipynb)

````
# Establish database connection
database = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = 'localhost',
    user = 'root',
    password = '',
    database = 'projects_0703'
)
# More about cursor: 
# https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor.html
mycursor = database.cursor()

# Fetch all companies records from the companies table from database
mycursor.execute('SELECT id, name FROM companies')
companies = mycursor.fetchall()

# Spreadsheet location
# location = ("./Cluster.xlsx")
location = input()

# Open the spreadsheet from the given path based on the sheet index
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(location)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(3)

# Fetch all the value from the sheet and store into an array
for excel_row in range(2, sheet.nrows):

    # Check respective fields are empty
    # Cell 26 = Techsector
    # Cell 27 = Sub-techsector
    if sheet.cell_value(excel_row, 26):
        category = categories[sheet.cell_value(excel_row, 26)]
    else:
        category = None
    if sheet.cell_value(excel_row, 27):
        subcategory = subcategories[sheet.cell_value(excel_row, 27)]
    else:
        subcategory = None

    # Assign ID = 10 if the stage is 0 in spreadsheet
    if sheet.cell_value(excel_row, 0) == 0:
        stage = 10
    else:
        stage = sheet.cell_value(excel_row, 0)

    # Replace NA into 0 for Manday
    if sheet.cell_value(excel_row, 19) == 'NA':
        manday = 0
    else:
        manday = sheet.cell_value(excel_row, 19)

    # Check if workbook's company exists in database company
    # Yes, fetch the company ID
    # No, create new company record and fetch the company ID
    if sheet.cell_value(excel_row, 1) in companies:
        for company in companies:
            if sheet.cell_value(excel_row, 1) == company[0][1]:
                company_id = company[0][0]
    else:
        if sheet.cell_value(excel_row, 3):
            # Get the industry ID from industries dictionary
            industry_id = industries[sheet.cell_value(excel_row, 3)]
            mycursor.execute('INSERT INTO companies(industry_id, name, category, country, source, created_at, updated_at) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, NOW(), NOW())', (industry_id, sheet.cell_value(excel_row, 1), 'a:1:{i:0;s:6:"Client";}', 'SINGAPORE', '0703',),)
            company_id = mycursor.lastrowid
            database.commit()

    # Create new project record
    mycursor.execute('INSERT INTO projects(company_id, source_id, stage_id, service_id, leader_id, category_id, subcategory_id, name, revenue, forecast, quotation, remarks, created_at, updated_at) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, NOW(), NOW())', (company_id, sources[sheet.cell_value(excel_row, 4)], stage, services[sheet.cell_value(excel_row, 5)], staffs[sheet.cell_value(excel_row, 20)], category, subcategory, sheet.cell_value(excel_row, 2), sheet.cell_value(excel_row, 17), sheet.cell_value(excel_row, 16), sheet.cell_value(excel_row, 18), sheet.cell_value(excel_row, 28)),)
    project_id = mycursor.lastrowid
    database.commit()

    # Check the number of project member in charge of the project
    # Create new project member record
    if sheet.cell_value(excel_row, 21):
        members = sheet.cell_value(excel_row, 21).split(',')
        for member in members:
            mycursor.execute('INSERT INTO member_project(member_id, project_id, manday, created_at, updated_at) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, NOW(), NOW())', (staffs[member.strip()], project_id, manday),)
    database.commit()

    # Create new project techpartner record
    # Cell 22 = Techpartner 1
    # Cell 23 = Techpartner 2
    # Cell 24 = Techpartner 3
    # Cell 25 = Techpartner 4
    for excel_cell in range(22, 26):
        techpartner = sheet.cell_value(excel_row, excel_cell)
        if techpartner:
            if techpartner in companies:
                for company in companies:
                    if techpartner == company[0][1]:
                        techpartner_id = company[0][0]
            else:
                mycursor.execute('INSERT INTO companies(name, category, country, source, created_at, updated_at) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, NOW(), NOW())', (techpartner, 'a:1:{i:0;s:7:\"Partner\";)', 'SINGAPORE', '0703',),)
                techpartner_id = mycursor.lastrowid
                database.commit()
            mycursor.execute('INSERT INTO project_techpartners(project_id, techpartner_id, created_at, updated_at) VALUES (%s, %s, NOW(), NOW())', (project_id, techpartner_id),)
        database.commit()
```
````

Comment: `workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(location)` Where is `xlrd` defined? Please include your imports.

Comment: @Mast I think that this is a reasonable excerpt, given the GitHub link that contains the full code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code isn't unreasonable. There are ways to clean it up, though.

### Functions

Organize your code into sub-routines - perhaps one to load categories from your spreadsheet, one to write information to your database, etc.

### Magic numbers

Numbers like 26, 27, 19, etc. should be assigned to constants, to make the code easier to understand.

### Ineffectual commit

The last line of your code is a commit after no operation. Perhaps this is just an indentation error and you meant to commit after your `execute`.

Delete the commit before it in the `else`. More broadly, you may want to consider reducing the number of commits in your code, maybe even to one at the end. This depends on a number of things, including how you want to deal with errors and whether they effect validity of the data as a whole, as well as performance.

Finally, have a read through https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-autocommit.html . The way you're using commits now, you're better off just turning on autocommit.

### Combined inserts

Your `insert into member_project` is inefficient. You should not insert in a loop. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html

### Add a prompt to your input()

Otherwise, the user doesn't know why the program has suddenly hung.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into it and improve my code.
Much appreciated.